# Integrating Javascript MVC frameworks with the backend

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm using a JS MVC framework (sammy) for the first time and I'm clueless about what is the preferred way of sending data to the backend. In my case I have a js object with all the data that I need to process and add in the database. It looks something like this -

```
object = { 1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], .... };
```

Should I use jQuery's Get (or Post) methods to send this via ajax or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to send the data to the server as JSON, using POST (or PUT), parse the JSON on the server and perform the necessary processing.

e.g. to send the data to the server using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SaveData.html',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: object,
    success: function (data) {
       // Add success handling here
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // Add error handling here
    }
});
```

On the server you can parse the JSON using a builtin function or third-party library e.g. I use [JSON .NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).